# how to solve error for Invalid Index to scalar variable

Tags: python, numpy

```
def sample_discrete(b):
        r = np.sum(b)*np.random.random();
        a = b[0].copy()
        i = 0
        while a < r:
            i += 1
            a += b[i]
        return i
def vectorize_sample_discrete(b,n= 10000): 
    samples = np.array([sample_discrete(b) for _ in range(n)])
    return samples

vfunc = np.vectorize(vectorize_sample_discrete)
b= np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.3,0.5,0.2,0.03])
(vfunc(b,n))
```

how to solve the error for Invalid Index to a scalar variable

Comment: I don't get why ppl are so hyped about `np.vectorize`. For loop is so much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Trace your values; this is basic debugging:

```
def vectorize_sample_discrete(b, n=10000):
    print("vectorize_sample_discrete", b)
    samples = np.array([sample_discrete(b) for _ in range(n)])
    return samples
```

This print `0.1`.  You *vectorized* the operation, remember?  The elements get handled individually, but in parallel (where supported by the run-time system).  Therefore, the `b` you deal with is a scalar, a float.  You pass that scalar into `sample_discrete`, where your attempt to copy the first element dies.

```
def sample_discrete(b):
    r = np.sum(b)*np.random.random()
    print("sample_discrete", b)
    a = b[0].copy()
```

`b` is still `0.1` here.  `0.1[0]` is an illegal reference.